# Selenium webdriver with firefox profile, checks addon compatilbility and won't start

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider the following code:

```
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\fdwfec0d.selenium')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(ffprofile)
```

When I run this code in a python script, Firefox shows a little window for checking addon compatibility and then doesn't start. The extension compatibility window closes and nothing else happens.

However, when I run the code in the interactive python shell, the browser successfully starts up after checking compatibility.

Anyone know what is going on? Can this be fixed?

The profile I am using has several extensions installed.

Python 2.7; Firefox 29.0.1; Selenium 2.41.0

Comment: Are you using the same python and selenium versions in both cases? Does downgrading to 2.40.0 help? Thanks.

Comment: @alexcxe It's the same version for everything in both cases.